# Is it possible to call WSHTTPBINDING from android?

Tags: android, .net, web-services, wcf-wshttpbinding, soap1.2

```
private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/IService1/HelloTest";
private static final String METHOD_NAME = "HelloTest";
private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
private static final String URL = "";  //blank for privacy
 SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
              //request.addProperty("Celsius", "32");    
                SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
                envelope.dotNet=true;
                envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
                HttpTransportSE ht = new HttpTransportSE(URL);                  
         try {
                ht.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);  
                final  SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();
                final String str = response.toString();
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, str, 5000).show();
                fetch_service.setText(str);     
             }
         catch (Exception e) {
                   e.printStackTrace();  
             }
```

I want to call my method (Hello Test). The result will be hello test return. But this sample is working for basic http binding but not working for wshttpbinding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    Element e = new Element();
        e.setName("To");
        e.setNamespace("http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing");
        e.addChild(Node.TEXT,
                "your URL HERE");


        Element e1 = new Element();
        e1.setName("Action");
        e1.setNamespace("http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing");
        e1.addChild(Node.TEXT,
                "http://tempuri.org/IService1/HelloTest");

    request.addProperty("Celsius", "32");    

    // use VER12 instead of VER11
    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER12);

    envelope.dotNet=true;

    // add HederOut to envelope
    envelope.headerOut = new Element[] { e, e1 };

    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
```

Comment: at last i have found the valuable answer from @Tarsem